# A Schema with multiple fact tables connecting to one dimension table

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, fact

I'm trying to create a Star Schema/Galaxy Schema in my datawarehouse and am trying to avoid creating a Snowflake Schema. I currently have 6 dim tables and 10 fact tables. Is it alright to have multiple fact tables connecting to one dimension table? E.g 4 Fact tables connecting with 1 Dim table.

Comment: Of course.  The whole point of using dimensions is to reuse them in all your fact tables (as long as the dimension applies to that fact table).  A snowflake schema means you link your fact to a dimension and that dimension links to another dimension.

Comment: If we assume, that all fact tables are assigned to at least one dimension (which is a very reasonable assumption in a DWH setup) you even have *no other chance* than to share dimensions between fact tables - as you have 10 fact tables but only six dimensions...

Comment: Thanks guys, for the info :) Though I'm not able to put a 'tick' on the comments section